# SQL - Select x most recent rows with common column value

Tags: php, mysql

**Example**

I would like to select the 5 most recent rows that have the same group value from the following table.

```
--------------------------------------------
|    id    |    group    |    timestamp    |
--------------------------------------------
|    1     |    circle   |    1468287300   |
|    2     |    square   |    1468287816   |
|    3     |    square   |    1468287694   |
|    4     |    circle   |    1468287252   |
|    5     |    circle   |    1468287987   |
|    6     |    circle   |    1468287068   |
|    7     |    square   |    1468287149   |
|    8     |    circle   |    1468287422   |
--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work, please check and let me know

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 GROUP BY group ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: That gave me an error, but I tried the following and it worked.


    SELECT * FROM table WHERE group="circle" ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 5;

Comment: Ohh Yes, we don't need `MAX(id)` when we are using `ORDER BY DESC` with `LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.`id`, t.`group`, t.`timestamp`
FROM (
   SELECT
        t1.*,
        IF(@grp = `group`, @rowno := @rowno + 1, @rowno := 1) AS rowno,
        @grp := `group`
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM yourtable
        ORDER BY `group`, `timestamp` DESC
    ) t1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @grp := null, @rowno := 0) t2
) t
WHERE rowno < 6
```

### SQLFiddle Demo